# How should i check if a post is saved

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say i have a database with users and posts tables

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  username string,
)

CREATE TABLE posts(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
)
```

And i want the user to have the ability to save a post so i created two tables

```
CREATE TABLE user_saved_posts(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
)

CREATE TABLE saved_post(
  user_saved_post_id INT REFERENCES user_saved_posts(id),
  post_id INT REFERENCES posts(id)
)
```

What i want to do is when i show those posts on the frontend I to show a UI indicator that if this post is saved or not

i thought about two solutions but I'm not sure which one is the best,

- The first is to do it on the frontend
  and comparing each post id with the saved ones
  `SELECT post_id FROM saved_post WHERE user_saved_post_id=$1`
  but this solution would be bad if the user have a lot of saved post.
- The second is to directly checking from the database

  ```
  SELECT p.body,(SELECT (
      case when exists
              (SELECT post_id FROM WHERE users_saved_posts = $1 AND post_id = p.id) 
              then true
              else false
      end
  ) as is_post_saved)
  FROM posts p
  ```

I'm thinking that the second solution is the better one, I hope you have better ideas than mine, So what you think?

Comment: Note: the result of `EXISTS(...)` is a boolean, so you don't need the `CASE ...` expression. Also: `create table` uses `()`, not `{}`

Comment: You should mention which front end UI technology you are using. Normally there are ways available to show on UI once your request to save post to db is finished successfully. For example, you will get return value or response code once DB operation is successfully completed.

Comment: @ChinmayT I already done what you said I'm showing an indicator when i press the button "save post" and checking the response code, What i want is to show indicator if the post is saved when fetching the post again, I'm using react btw